# Rails admin with zeitwerk

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, gemfile, ruby-3, zeitwerk

Hi i am having a application built in rails 6 and i am trying to update it to rails 7 but there's some problem i am facing with zeitwerk.

in the rails admin initilizer

```
# initilizer/rails_admin.rb
require 'rails_admin/main_controller'
```

i am having above code. but it is giving me `NameError: uninitialized constant RailsAdmin::ApplicationController`

i tried `require 'rails_admin/application_controller`
but then i get uninitialized constant ApplicationController and then it goes on like i have to require everything which application controller is using

My rails admin version is 3.0.0 and ruby 3

Comment: This is unrelated to Zeitwerk. In Rails 6 autoloading reloadable code in initializers was deprecated and when the application booted warnings were issued. In Rails 7, you cannot do that anymore, but this is because it didn't make sense conceptually, does not depend on Zeitwerk. Why are you loading a controller there?

Comment: i need to do some monkey patching here in initializer. i dont know why they did not do it in rails 6. this is due to zeitwerk only as it was working fine with classic mode @XavierNoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is unrelated to Zeitwerk.

In Rails 6, autoloading reloadable code from the initializers was deprecated, and warnings were issued. These warnings were issued both in classic and in zeitwerk mode. This feature has been removed from Rails 7.

This is explained in the [upgrading guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#autoloading-during-initialization).

Controllers in Rails engines are reloadable, and therefore this new rule applies. Please decorate the controller in a `to_prepare` block as documented in the [autoloading guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#use-case-1-during-boot-load-reloadable-code).

Also, please do not issue `require` calls for reloadable code, just use the `RailsAdmin::MainController` constant directly.

Comment: main controller is defined in rails_admin gem

Comment: RailsAdmin::MainController is not being loaded in the initializer/rails_amin.rb

Comment: Yes it is defined in the rails_admin gem, which is an engine. That controller is reloadable just like your controllers are, because engines get reloaded together with the application. Please, don't use `require` for reloadable code, and follow the documentation linked above to be able to decorate the controller in an initializer. Happy to provide more help if needed.

Comment: i did resolved it. thanks! but i am getting similar error on running `rails zeitwerk:check` 
NameError: uninitialized constant RailsAdmin::BreakAllocation
and i have this line in the initializers/rails_admin.rb

require Rails.root.join('lib', 'rails_admin', 'break_allocation.rb')

`
module RailsAdmin
    module Config
      module Actions
        class BreakAllocation < Base

`

Comment: Doing that should be fine. I assume that file defines `RailsAdmin::BreakAllocation`. Neither that file, nor that constant are managed by Zeitwerk, assuming `lib` is not in the autoload paths (you can check with `bin/rails runner 'pp Rails.autoloaders.main.dirs'`, please followup if it is there). Seems like a regular NameError from Ruby (Zeitwerk raises `Zeitwerk::NameError`). Where is that error raised?